# Static object null issue while app goes to background for long time and return back

Tags: android, static

I have a one scenario :

- Have stored some information regarding my app user in static object and
  Can access object from anywhere from my app
- Upto this all works fine
- **But when I press home button and app is in background for long time or I open other apps which consume memory all static objects of my app becomes null**
- And I get NullPointerException

After a lot debugging I think it may be because memory issue but I cant find any solution.

Is their any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your process is being terminated while it is in the background. [This is perfectly normal](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). You cannot assume that any `static` fields will be populated when any of your activities are created. Either:

- Remove the `static` field, or
- Access the `static` field only through a method that can lazy-initialize that field, or
- Switch to something like dependency injection

Answer (score 1):

Such an issue could occur in case under extreme memory pressure, system can kill your app processes, resetting all the static fields to default which would be null in your case.

So, to avoid it I will suggest you to use **SharedPreferences**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SharedPreferences` to store user information. This keeps data even after the app is terminated. Usage:

```
SharedPreferences pref = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putString("user_name", "User"); //store data
String userName = pref.getString("user_name"); //get data
```